# Couldn't find PhpStorm.sh file ( Ubuntu 14.04 ) LTE

Tags: php, ide, editor

Downloaded PhpStorm (PhpStorm-8.0.2.tar.gz) from https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/

Instructions:

- Unpack the PhpStorm-*.tar.gz file using the following command:
     ***tar xfz PhpStorm-*.tar.gz***
- Run PhpStorm.sh from the bin subdirectory

As instructions, I unpacked the file but I am not able to find **PhpStorm.sh** file in the bin subdirectory, there are only two file **idea.properties** and **log.xml** in bin directory.

Please help anyone how can I create that file or run PhpStorm? Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward. Are you sure you're in the correct directory? I actually installed this just the other day. This should work:

```
tar xfz PhpStorm-*.tar.gz
cd PhpStorm-139.732/bin
./phpstorm.sh
```

Pay attention to the version in the PhpStorm folder name.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am in the correct directory. And I downloaded twice this zip file to sure it is not damaged.

Comment: can you please upload somewhere PhpStorm.sh file . thanks

Comment: The phpstorm.sh file is available as part of the zip file from the link in your original post. I just downloaded the zip file from that link and confirmed it. If you run the commands that I posted in the directory where you downloaded the zip it will work.

Comment: Downloaded again and now file is there, thanks mkasberg.